# GPU Temperature

Tags: gpu, temperature, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an NVIDIA GeForce GT 430 graphics card. I'm getting a temperature of 39-40.0°C in idle, is that ok? Whats the ideal temperature for that card on idle?

Comment: I have seen cards work fine at 80°C.  It is normal to see 40°C-50°C

Comment: It's fine, don't worry.

Comment: @Catalyst I converted to a comment because it was short, and though technically an answer, I felt that it was better as a comment, unless you expanded it a little more...Feel free  to edit your comment and expand, and undelete if you like. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by reading the [specs of your graphic card](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gt-430-us.html) you can see that the (safe) maximum temperature is something near 98°C. everything below is ok. the temperature of your graphic card should be room temperature (20°C) if you have turned your machine off. so, 45°C are just additional 20°C ontop of the "bottom" line, which is absolutely fine. my (passivly cooled) gt430 idles around 50-55°C, gaming pushes that up to 80-90°C.

Comment: Note that when your system boots, things like GPUs heat up very quickly. The coolest I've ever been able to measure with my desktop is about 35°C, while my room is about 20°C. For CPUs you should be in the range of 30~780°C, GPUs in general get hotter, but never let it pass 95~100°C ! Ideally you should keep them below 80°C but that's not always possible. (not idle, this is full load, idle should be around 40°C, lower is better)